# Неполнота предложения

Tags: untagged

Разве пропуск местоимений 1 и 2 лица влияет на полноту?"

> Возьмем пример: "Ты меня любишь? Люблю!"

Второе предложение считается неполным двусоставным или односоставным?

---

Насколько я знаю, по форме глагола 1 и 2 лица и так понятно, кто имеется в виду (в данном случае [я]), при этом местоимение для пояснения не требуется. Однако смущает тот факт, что восстанавливаем все предложение: я тебя люблю, а не просто "люблю тебя".

Comment: Неполное односоставное (определенно-личное). Пропущенное дополнение определяется по контексту.

Comment: Шерон, то есть определенно-личные вообще не могут считаться ни в каких контекстах неполными двусоставными?

Comment: Думаю,что нет.  У них в грамматическую основу входит только один член (сказуемое).  Распространять предложение могут второстепенные члены. Если они пропущены и восстанавливаются по контексту, то предложение считается неполным.  Об односоставных предложениях: http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#32

Comment: Про второстепенные все понятно, Спасибо.

Comment: Шерон. Еще такой вопрос. Про несогласованное определение и дополнение. Есть ли четкие критерии разграничения? Грамота писала статью о том, что несогласованное определение совмещает свое значение с дополнением или обстоятельством. Знаю, что для заданий обычно отбирают примеры, в которых нет "глагольности" у опорного слова, но тут на глаза мне попался пример: "варенье из вишни". Опорное слово-то от глагола образовано (варить), почему нельзя заменить на "варить (что-то) из вишни". Почему-то большинство считает, что это только несогласованное определение.

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, отвечу чуть позже

Comment: Хорошо. Буду ждать.

Comment: Из грамматики: Дополнениями считаются такие падежные и предложно-падежные формы, которые соответствуют объекту в соотносительных конструкциях с глаголами: стр. 81. Неразложимые сочетанная стр.6. Почитайте, возможно, вам тема стане яснее. А вообще говоря, второстепенные члены предложения больше связаны с семантикой, а не грамматикой, поэтому удобно ориентироваться ся на те естественные вопросы, которые мы задаем в нашей реальной речи. В разных ситуациях они могут меняться, тогда проявляются дополнительные (определительные) значения.

Comment: Кстати, процесс называется варкой, варением, а варенье - это продукт. Ссылка на учебник https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf Кстати,  в новых изданиях есть изменения, но не очень существенные, но эти книги трудно найти онлайн.

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Возникло много вопросов. 1) Имеет ли смысл в школьной грамматике разграничивать дополнение/обстоятельство и несогласованное определение?

Comment: 2) Нас всегда учили, что дополнение/обстоятельство не могут зависеть от подлежащего, не соотносящегося с глаголом. Это так? Если да, то как объяснить этот пример: "невзрачность он неухоженности". Возьмем такой пример, где опорное будет подлежащим: "Невзрачность от неухоженности всегда была его недостатком". Я бы в этом примере видел несогласованное определение с оттенком обстоятельства, а не наоборот.

Comment: 3)Недавно я проверял задание, одним методистом для морфологического разбора было дано слово "трамваев" в сочетании "дребезжание трамваев". По логике автора это чистое дополнение. Учебник, как я понимаю, будет руководствоваться другой логикой: дребезжание трамваев = трамваи дребезжат. Нет объекта действия, зато есть субъект. Значит, это несогласованное определение.

Comment: @Ajgy дребезжание трамваев =/= трамваи дребезжат, это не дребезжащие трамваи. (существительное изменено на глагол). Дребезжать могут не трамваи, а рельсы или провода, дребезжание слышится при проезде трамваев - тут нет предиката, поэтому нет никакой субъект-объектности, просто дополнение.

Comment: Вопрос удалëнного аккаунта. Уверен, что это Ajgy.

Answer (score 0):

Если не считать такие предложения неопределённо-личными, то что тогда считать? Просто считайте предложения, где пропущено подлежащее неопределённо-личными, вот и всё. Относитесь к этому как к простой условности при строительстве терминологии, чем оно собственно и является. Что касается предложения: ‟Люблю”, то здесь неопределённо-личное и неполное, где ещё пропущено слово ‟тебя”.

Comment: С каких пор предложение "Я люблю тебя" является неопределенно-личным?

Comment: ‟Люблю” – неопределённо личное, а не: ‟Я люблю тебя”.

Comment: А-а, это другое дело. А то у вас "Я люблю..."

Comment: Вы меня справедливо поправили.